# improper integral-integral test for convergence:$\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\cos (\ln x)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Verify the convergence of the improper integral
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\cos (\ln x)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} \mathrm dx.$$

I split this integral into two parts. I know how to prove its convergence from $1$ to infinity, but I can't prove the convergence of the second part which is from $0$ to $1$ can someone help?
I tried integrating by parts but it didn't work for me.
(Sorry if the language is not fully understandable, English is not my first language the exact math terms so I searched for them on Google.)

Comment: How did you prove the integral converges over $[1,\infty)$?

Comment: Consider $\cos(\ln(x))=\Re[x^i]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the absolute convergence for the $\int^1_0\frac{\cos(\ln(x))}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}dx$. With this, you can: $\int^1_0\frac{|\cos(\ln(x))|}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}dx\leq \int^1_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}dx$ and value of this integral is finite, since the function is continuous and the interval is bounded. The same could be done for the $[1,+\infty)$ part.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\cos (\ln x)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} \mathrm dx&=  \int_0^1 \frac{\cos (\ln x)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} d x+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\ln x)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} d x \\
& =\int_{\infty}^1 \frac{\cos \left(\ln \frac{1}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^4}+1}} \frac{d x}{-x^2}+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\ln x)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} d x \quad \textrm{ via }x\mapsto \frac{1}{x} \\
& =2 \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\ln x)}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
If you had proved that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\ln x)}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} d x$ is convergent, then $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\cos (\ln x)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} \mathrm dx$ is convergent too.

Answer (score 2):

The integral converges absolutely by comparison with
$$
\int_0^\infty
\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} = \frac14B\left(\frac14, \frac14\right) .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^4+1\ge {1\over 2}(x^2+1)^2$ we get  $${|\cos\ln x|\over \sqrt{x^4+1}}\le {\sqrt{2}\over x^2+1}$$and $$\sqrt{2}\int\limits_0^\infty {dx\over x^2+1}=\sqrt{2}\arctan x\bigg\vert _0^\infty={\pi\over \sqrt{2}} $$ Hence the integral in question is absolutely convergent.